# Invalid propTypes warning when used with a npm package

Tags: reactjs, npm, immutable.js, react-proptypes

I've extracted some stuff from my react application into a separate npm package. Everything works, but I have some propTypes warnings I cannot get rid of and they were not there before the extraction.

I'm using propTypes as follows:

```
MyClass.propTypes = {
    mapField: PropTypes.instanceOf(Immutable.Map).isRequired,
};
```

The warning is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `mapField` of type `Map` 
supplied to `MyClass`, expected instance of `Map`.
```

Both the extracted npm package and the host application use the same versions for all the common dependencies.

I am 100% sure that `mapField` is an instance of `Immutable.Map`. 
The issue occurs for other classes as well, such as `moment`, `Immutable.List`.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. The problem was I was not using `immutable` as a peerDependency in the npm module I've created. Even though it had the same version, it did not work.